# Passing UTM Parameters Across WP Link (Working with bugs need advice)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, utm-tracking

This code DOES work, however I can't make it stop adding blank UTM to the other links.

The way it should work is if there are no UTM strings set it does nothing. This snippet passes the UTM data onto other links across the site so we can use UTM paramaters across the site to trigger show/hide content.

```
<?php $utm_source = isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : ""; ?>
<?php $utm_medium = isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : ""; ?>
<?php $utm_campaign = isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : ""; ?>
<?php $utm_term = isset($_GET['utm_term']) ? $_GET['utm_term'] : ""; ?>
<?php $utm_content = isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : ""; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(function() {
$("a").attr('href', function(i, h) {
return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&utm_source=<?php echo $utm_source; ?>&utm_medium=<?php echo $utm_medium; ?>&utm_campaign=<?php echo $utm_campaign; ?>&utm_term=<?php echo $utm_term; ?>&utm_content=<?php echo $utm_content; ?>" : "?utm_source=<?php echo $utm_source; ?>&utm_medium=<?php echo $utm_medium; ?>&utm_campaign=<?php echo $utm_campaign; ?>&utm_term=<?php echo $utm_term; ?>&utm_content=<?php echo $utm_content; ?>");
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: If a user visits domain.com/ it should not set the links. If they visit domain.com with utm parameters then it should set the utm passing links

Comment: So wrap the whole JS output into a PHP `if`, that checks whether all those variables contain something or not?

Comment: So like an "if domain.com" then don't do anything - if domain.com/utm do this